# Soluble-by-finite group

Tags: group-theory

Could someone give me the definition of "soluble-by-finite group"? I have searched in several books, but they always refer to this type of groups without giving a clear definition. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

It almost certainly means a group $G$ with a normal soluble subgroup $N$ such that $G/N$ is finite.

More generally, if ${\mathcal P}$ and ${\mathcal Q}$ are two properties that groups may have, sich as abelian, soluble, finite, torsion-free, etc, then a group is ${\mathcal P}$-by-${\mathcal Q}$ if it has a normal subgroup $N$ with property ${\mathcal P}$ such that $G/N$ has property ${\mathcal Q}$.

Unfortunately, some people do this the other way round, and they mean a group with a normal subgroup $N$ with property ${\mathcal Q}$ such that $G/N$ has property ${\mathcal P}$. But, in my experience, ${\mathcal P}$-by-finite or, equivalently, virtually ${\mathcal P}$, virtually always means that the finite bit is at the top of the group.

Answer (score 1):

Definition: A group $\;G\;$  is $\;\mathfrak X\;\;by\;\;\mathfrak Y\;\;$ if it has a normal subgroup $\;N\;$ s.t. $\;N\;$ is $\;\mathfrak X\;$ and $\;G/N\;$ is $\;\mathfrak Y\;$.

Thus, a group is soluble-by-finite, also called *virtually soluble*, if it has a soluble group of finite index.